# I am new in python I was trying to perform read/write operations but I got this error ->FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory error?

Tags: python, read-write, nosuchfileexception

I found this solution from stackoverflow but will i have to add this piece of code every time i write a code to perform read/write operations.
Or is there any long term solution available for this ?

```
import os

path = "E:\Python\learn"
os.chdir(path)

f = open('text.txt') 
data = f.read()
print(data)
f.close()
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To be clear: what you want the code to do, is look in the `E:\Python\learn` folder, and open the `test.txt` file in there? And when you try to do this, you get an error message that says there is not such a file? I can't understand why there is a question. The error already told you exactly what is wrong. What do you think should happen, if you try to read from a file that is not there? Or do you think the file should be there? If so, **why**? Also: please read [ask] and try to communicate more clearly. The title does not seem to have much to do with the post.

Comment: You need to either use `r"..."` for your path or escape the backslashes. Use `with` to read and automatically close the file. You don't need to always `chdir` somewhere, you can put the full path in the `open` call. I'd suggest you read the Python documentation on file I/O. I haven't seen a programming language yet where you don't have to open a file before reading or writing it. so there isn't a way around opening files, but it can be written much more elegant and pythonic than what you posted.

Comment: I was writing an I/O code in python in VS code, but when I was trying to use the text from another file it gave me this error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Python\learn\24_readline.py", line 7, in <module>
    f = open('sample.txt', 'r') 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sample.txt'
So when I searched on google, I found a solution that suggested me to add the lines below in my program.
import os
path = "E:\Python\learn"
os.chdir(path)                Do I have to introduce this piece of the code every time I do a I/O program.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need a way to read same file multiple times in your python code. Use file.seek() to jump to a specific position in a file. However, think about whether it is really necessary to go through the file again. An Example for file.seek:

```
with open(name, 'r+') as file:
for line in file:
    # Do Something with line
file.seek(0)
for line in file:
    # Do Something with line, second time
```

Incase you want to re-iterate the file second time and don't want to open the file again, you can follow this syntax:

```
with open(name, 'r+') as file:
            for line in file:
                # Do Something with line
            for line in file:
                # Do Something with line, second time
```